# Why isn't this working in Opera?

Tags: internet-explorer, opera

So I've build a little website, it uses a lot of CSS3 animations, and I've tested it in other browsers ( I usually work with Chrome ), and I noticed that Opera doesn't show anything, it's like the `opacity` remains `0`.

Update: I've just noticed that neither IE latest version behaves, the same as Opera.

Link: http://rolandgroza.com/projects/tcsg/ ;

Can someone tell me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera 12 adds support for CSS3 Animations.  If you tested in 11.6x, it won't show any animations.  Opera 12 beta is out now, so please test and see if it works better.

Comment: What about IE ? The same behavior :|

Answer (score 0):

Opera does not support CSS3 animations at this time. You could something like http://modernizr.com/ to trigger animations only for supporting browsers. Animations should enhance existing content.